# Lemoon CMS setup, Visual Studio 2013, Windows 10, IISExpress error

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, onedrive, lemoon

Installed Visual Studio 2013 so that I can use Lemoon template from Extensions and Updates ..

I got the following setup error:

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

Configuring IIS Express failed with the following error:

Filename: \?\C:\Users\NNNN\OneDrive\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationHost.config

Error: Cannot write configuration file

The file exists and I have given Everyone full access.

I have started VS 2013 as Administrator but to no avail.

I have also tried with VS 2012, Administrator.

Comment: Have you tried launching Visual Studio as an administrator?

Comment: It works when I don't have my default documents folder "Protected" by OneDrive. So, I disabled OneDrive Protection in the settings. But now my documents aren't backed up to OneDrive. Why can't I have both?